# create a graph with the dataset in order to use GNN on it

Tags: python-3.x, graph, material-design, structure

I have the dataset that contains material id, chemical formula, and thermoelectric properties of each material and I would like to use GNN to predict one thermoelectric property.

first I have create a structure for all the molecule of my dataset.
and would like now to create a graph for my dataset include nodes attributes and bond attribute.
but I have no idea.

this is the code to get structure

from pymatgen.ext.matproj import MPRester
`import pandas as pd`

`api_key = "this was my api"`

`structures = []`
`with MPRester(api_key) as m:`
 `for material_id in df['mpid']:`
`structure = m.get_structure_by_material_id(material_id)`
`structures.append(structure)`

`data = {"material_id": materials, "structure": structures}`
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok my dataset contains many perovskite materials. and Seebeck coefficient, resistivity, power factor, thermal conductivity,  and I would like to use graph convolutional network to predict the Seebeck coefficient

Answer (score 0):

> to create a graph for my dataset include nodes attributes and bond
> attribute

Could you add some more detail on what you expect this graph to be like, perhaps with an example for a few small simple molecules?

I cannot tell from your question, as it is, what exactly you are looking for.  In case it might be interesting for you, here is a screenshot of my application to visualize and find similar biological compounds that are entered using SMILES https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system

[image]

The complete application is at https://github.com/JamesBremner/chemgraph

Comment: Thank you . but if I use your application, how can I use those different graph as input for my graph convolutional model?

Comment: To answer that, you need to clarify what your input is like and what output you need for your graph.  Do you have a SMILES representation of your input, or are you using something else.  What does the graph model need as input.